# Changing attributes of a span element which is outside a nested span

Tags: css

## Question

I want to access the span text and change its color.
How can I do this in the following setup?

## Code

```
<div class="element">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" ng-if="true">button</span>
    </button>
    <span class="title">Change this color</span>
</div>
```

## Suggestion

```
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-play[ng-if="true"] span.title  {
    color:red;
}
```

This doesn't work unfortunately.

## JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/916g3bea/2/

Comment: As you see, the attribute I want to change depends on the other attribute in the parent span. Its always the span before. So maybe something like next span first-child or something might work?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't traverse back in the DOM to select the next `span` element by pure CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately. I expected this answer. I will need to write the attribute somewhere else then.

Comment: By any chance if you could give that attribute to the `button` you could simply target the next span by `button[ng-if="true"] + span` combinator.

Comment: You need to use jquery to achieve this.

Comment: Sure jquery is a way, I wanted to try this with pure css. Are the specs for CSS4 maybe updated to achieve this one time?

Comment: @gco There's no such thing in CSS selector level 4. This is against the cascading nature of CSS. The closet thing has been added is to specify the [subject of a selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) by a leading `!`. E.g. `!OL > LI:only-child` would target the `OL` element having only one `LI` child. Also note that this is not implemented in any of web browsers at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-play[ng-if="true"], span.title {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Sure your right, but this will make it always red. I need it to be red if the given attribute is set as so. I'll make my question clearer. ty though.